# Mechanism behind password storage in sudo

Tags: sudo, password

Whats the mechanism behind sudo that stores the password for all subsequent calls to sudo?

Comment: In Debian, it's under `/var/lib/sudo/ts/<username>`, with permissions `0600`. At least, if you delete that file, all that user's terminals have to enter the password again. On other systems it might be stored elsewhere.

Comment: It's not storing your password, just a time stamp file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clarify, sudo uses a timestamp cache file (configured at build time with --with-rundir) and stores a [timestamp](https://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/file/cdbe432c465c/plugins/sudoers/timestamp.c) entry (see ts_write() with it's struct timestamp argument) to the file. That struct is defined

```
struct ts_cookie {
    char *fname;
    int fd;
    pid_t sid;
    bool locked;
    off_t pos;
    struct timestamp_entry key;
};
```

where fname is set as the path to the cache file (and not the user's password) -- see timestamp_open() where it uses `asprintf(&fname, "%s/%s", def_timestampdir, user)` to set `fname`.